# Function in Stack template wont return 0;

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I'm trying to make my own version of Stack using templates. The first version of the code compiles and works fine when i call the functions.

1.

```
template <typename T, int size = 60>
struct Stack{
T data[size];
int top_el;
Stack():top_el(-1){}
void push(T el){
    data[++top_el] = el;
}
void pop(){
    if (top_el==-1) return;
    else top_el = top_el-1;
};
void top(){
    if (top_el==-1) return;
    else    cout<<data[top_el].var<<endl;
};
bool empty(){
    return top_el == -1;
    }
};
```

2.

```
template <typename T, int size = 60>
struct Stack{
T data[size];
int top_el;
Stack():top_el(-1){}
void push(T el){
    data[++top_el] = el;
}
T pop(){
    if (top_el==-1) return 0;
    else return data[top_el--];
};
T top(){
    if (top_el==-1) return 0;
    else    return data[top_elt];
};
bool empty(){
    return top_el == -1;
    }
};
```

the second code compiles too, but when i call the functions top() or pop() somewhere in the code, and then try to compile I get the following error message:

> ERROR: could not convert '0' from 'int' to 'man'

at the following lines

```
if (top_el==-1) return 0;
```

And i'm strictly not allowed to use class.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There isn't enough here to compile.

Comment: So, the error is clearly pointed out by the compiler. You cannot `return 0` from a function that is declared to return `T` (i.e. `man` in your specific case). It is really a question to you: why are you trying to `return 0` from these functions? What did you mean by that?

Comment: What, in your opinion, should `return 0;` do when your function returns a `T`, which is class `man`?

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity for an `assert` (stdlib style) or an exception, to me.